# javascript animate method

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create a method for animation like in jQuery. I cannot use any framework. I need this method in javascript (Chrome, Safari, Mozilla, Opera).

```
animate(obj, {property1: val, property2: val...}, time, callback);
```

Comment: Are the properties CSS properties that hold numeric values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full animation framework in 51 lines.

https://github.com/madrobby/emile/blob/master/emile.js

I know you said you can't use any "framework", but if I copied/pasted the code here, it would still be a framework in that sense.